# Validate user on update request in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I want to have an API where a user can update his own listings. Currently any authenticated user can update any listing which I found using Postman. I want to validate the user so that the API returns an error as a response if the user is not trying to update his own listing. Here is my code:

```
# serializers.py

class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Listing
    fields = '__all__'

# api.py

class ListingViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Listing.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

# urls.py

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('api/listings', ListingViewSet, 'listings')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to overwrite the `perform_update` function:

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    obj = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user != obj.created_by:  # Or how ever you validate
        raise PermissionDenied('User is not allowed to modify listing')

    serializer.save()
```

You will need:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
```

Comment: @Blomqma you need to click on the “check” icon to accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the object for all method change the main queryset. In this case if an inapropiate user try to access an invalid object the api return 404.

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    return Listing.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```